# Looking way to make generic out of this code

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, generics

I have code where i am passing bunch of inputs to the method and adding to the database with entities inside that method like the below

```
public class SpaceTypeServices
{
    public Guid CreateRequest(
       SpaceTypeInput spaceTypeInput,
       MasterSection masterSection,
       RequestInput requestInputs,
       APIDbContext dbContext)
    {      
        var id = Guid.NewGuid();
        var mechanicalData = new MechanicalData();
        var mechanicalTypeData = new MechanicalTypeData();

        var environmentCondition = new EnvironmentConditions
        {
            ConditionType = spaceTypeInput.EnvironmentConditionsInput.ConditionType,
            CoolingSetPointOccupied = spaceTypeInput.EnvironmentConditionsInput.CoolingSetPointOccupied ?? 0,
            CoolingSetPointUnOccupied = spaceTypeInput.EnvironmentConditionsInput.CoolingSetPointUnOccupied ?? 0,
            HeatingSetPointOccupied = spaceTypeInput.EnvironmentConditionsInput.HeatingSetPointOccupied ?? 0,
            RelativeHumidityMax = spaceTypeInput.EnvironmentConditionsInput.RelativeHumidityMax ?? 0,
            RelativeHumidityMin = spaceTypeInput.EnvironmentConditionsInput.RelativeHumidityMin ?? 0
        };
        var exhaustType = new Exhaust
        {
            AirflowPerArea = spaceTypeInput.ExhaustInput.AirflowPerArea ?? 0,
            AirflowPerFixture = spaceTypeInput.ExhaustInput.AirflowPerFixture ?? 0,
            MaxExhaustAirChange = spaceTypeInput.ExhaustInput.MaxExhaustAirChange ?? 0,
            MinExhaustAirChange = spaceTypeInput.ExhaustInput.MinExhaustAirChange ?? 0,
            ExhaustSource = spaceTypeInput.ExhaustInput.ExhaustSource
        };
        var thermalComfort = new ThermalComfort
        {
            AirSpeed = spaceTypeInput.ThermalComfortInput.AirSpeed ?? 0,
            ClothingInsulation = spaceTypeInput.ThermalComfortInput.ClothingInsulation ?? 0,
            MetabolicRate = spaceTypeInput.ThermalComfortInput.MetabolicRate ?? 0
        };

        // bunch of code same like as above object initialization

        mechanicalData.Exhaust = exhaustType;
        mechanicalData.Environment = environmentCondition;
        mechanicalData.ThermalComfort = thermalComfort;
        // bunch of assigning objects 

        mechanicalTypeData.MechanicalData = mechanicalData;

        var spaceType = new SpaceType
        {
            MechanicalTypeData = mechanicalTypeData,
            Description =  spaceTypeInput.Description,
        };

        dbContext.SpaceTypes.Add(spaceType);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return id;
    }
```

I am looking a way to convert this procedural to more generic way refactoring but could not be able to figure it out to do the same.

Could any one have any idea or any suggestions on how to refactor these things in more OO approach or generic way that would be very grateful to me.

many thanks in advance

**update :**

i am looking kind of generic method like this

```
  public T myFunction<T>(int id, string name) where T : class1, new()
   {
      T obj = new T();
      obj.id = id;
      obj.name = name;
      return obj;
   }
```

Comment: I think what you have is fine. If you want to make it hard to understand, complicated then use patterns. I would leave it alone unless there are parts that can be reused but even then I would ask if the reuse is "accidental duplication". If it is accidental duplication, leave it alone.

Comment: @CodingYoshi i am looking kind of creating generic method and pass these objects to method and return to the same with the same type .. but some how i am not able to figure it out

Comment: @CodingYoshi, constructing those types like this is making the code unnecessarily dependent on the construction of the dependent objects. IOW, the request must always change with those types. That's a SRP violation.

Comment: 1) Why are you looking for that? 2) What do you mean "creating generic message"?

Comment: i modified my comment sorry for confusion its method not message

Comment: @EnigmaState, this code is fairly specialized; it's not going to be "easy" to generalize (across different types?). But you can improve it even without patterns; just depends on what you want/need to do.

Comment: Your method is fine. It takes a few types as input, I guess you're using them as DTOs, and it creates a `SpaceType`. If anything I would change the method name to `CreateSpaceType` and within the method call smaller private methods to create things. Other than that it's fine.

Comment: thanks for suggestion i updated my code i am looking more kind of passing dto object to method and do the operations inside return the same just to make clear with generics

Comment: I don’t think a generic solution is what would work here. Generics work in situations where you have the same thing but the *type* changes. I don’t see how that would help here. Instead, what might work for you, and I usually really don’t recommend this lightly, would be AutoMapper because after all, you are mapping your input types to database types with identical property names.

Comment: @poke many thanks for the response , is there any other way to refactor this..

Comment: I don't think you have a good grasp on what generics are and for. Are you going to pass different types of objects to the `CreateRequest` method?

Comment: I am not looking for to convert createRequest method to generic, instead i am looking for to extract those 6 conditions like `environmentConditions, Exhaust..etc..` into generic method.

Answer (score 2):

> Could any one have any idea or any suggestions on how to refactor
>   these things in more OO approach or generic way that would be very
>   grateful to me.

Constructing an object with anything other than a parameter-less constructor creates some level of responsibility on the caller to know details about that object. The more complex the object construction is, the more burdensome it is on the caller. For example:

```
var environmentCondition = new EnvironmentConditions
{
    ConditionType = spaceTypeInput.EnvironmentConditionsInput.ConditionType,
    CoolingSetPointOccupied = spaceTypeInput.EnvironmentConditionsInput.CoolingSetPointOccupied ?? 0,
    CoolingSetPointUnOccupied = spaceTypeInput.EnvironmentConditionsInput.CoolingSetPointUnOccupied ?? 0,
    HeatingSetPointOccupied = spaceTypeInput.EnvironmentConditionsInput.HeatingSetPointOccupied ?? 0,
    RelativeHumidityMax = spaceTypeInput.EnvironmentConditionsInput.RelativeHumidityMax ?? 0,
    RelativeHumidityMin = spaceTypeInput.EnvironmentConditionsInput.RelativeHumidityMin ?? 0
};
```

This example shows that we're responsible for not only knowing that `EnvironmentConditions` depends on an `EnvironmentConditionsInput` (not so bad), but we also must know the properties of both and worse, we must perform the error checking/default values. Because this is done explicitly in the callers, the construction code is required to be repeated *correctly* everywhere an `EnvironmentConditions` is created. This becomes a real issue if these classes change.

Let's assume the definition of `EnvironmentConditions` requires another property. That will require every instance of this code to be changed to support the new property correctly. If there is "a bunch of code" doing this, the request code has a *bunch of reasons to change* possibly for different reasons, at different times, at different frequencies; does the service and its developers really need to worry about all that? Why not just pass the input object into the conditions class and have this code change applied everywhere at once?

```
public class EnvironmentConditions
{
    ...
    public EnvironmentConditions(EnvironmentConditionsInput input)
    {
        ConditionType = input.ConditionType;
        CoolingSetPointOccupied = input.CoolingSetPointOccupied ?? 0;
        CoolingSetPointUnOccupied = input.CoolingSetPointUnOccupied ?? 0;
        HeatingSetPointOccupied = input.HeatingSetPointOccupied ?? 0;
        RelativeHumidityMax = input.RelativeHumidityMax ?? 0;
        RelativeHumidityMin = input.RelativeHumidityMin ?? 0;
        // some new property
    }
}
// new EnvironmentConditions(spaceTypeInput.EnvironmentConditionsInput);
```

This could be done for all similar code and the `SpaceType` as well. If so, the remaining space related code could be as simple as:

```
public class SpaceTypeServices
{
    public Guid CreateRequest(...)
    {    
        // rest  
        var spaceType = new SpaceType(spaceTypeInput);
        dbContext.SpaceTypes.Add(spaceType);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return id;
    }
}
```

This is a low impact, low effort refactoring that at the very least makes the code easier to maintain and reduces complexity.

Comment: I need to have parameter less constructor for these classes , otherwise i am getting error when retrieving the same from database. I am using postgresSQL with Entity framework core poco classes

Comment: @EnigmaState, I don't think that will impact this refactoring. If something is requiring you to provide a parameter-less ctor then so be it. If you didn't have that requirement, I would recommend making it private so you could enforce a known construction; that's not the case though. When *you're* doing the instantiation (not EF), what's the problem with providing a convenient ctor?

Comment: I am using graphql query to get the data and those tables are stored as json objects in one of the column .. and when i am going to retrieve the data for the same column through the playground(swagger for rest) i am getting that constructor error

Comment: is there any generic approach that would be very grateful to me

Comment: @EnigmaState, are you saying that if these classes have *both* a parameter-less ctor *and* the one I'm suggesting, it throws exceptions?

Comment: yes, for these classes there should be a parameter less constructor

Comment: @EnigmaState, yes, I understand that. But is there a problem with providing the parameter-less one ***and** others*?

Comment: yeah there is s problem for providing parameter constructor when i am calling `getspacetypes` through graphql query.. But any way thank you for all your suggestions.